# facebook api is not returning birthday data

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Code below:

```
//set permissions for graph api
var permissions = ['user_friends','user_birthday','user_photos','basic_info'];
var facebookModule = facebookHelper.FacebookConnection(permissions);

//event handler to listen to user when they have logged in
facebookModule.addEventListener('login', function(e){
   if(e.success){
       //before setting model we want to see if data exists already in database
       alert('You were Logged in');
       //get me data upon success
       facebookModule.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
           if (e.success) {
              console.log(e.result);    
           } else if (e.error) {
              alert(e.error);
           } else {
              alert('Unknown response');
           }
       });
```

It is returning an incomplete JSON object.

Comment: What do you mean by `an incomplete JSON object`?

Comment: Basically all the fields I want except birthday

Comment: Did you granted the birthday permission, when the permission dialog appeared?

Comment: Thanks Sahil, that was the problem. I added the birthday permission after already accepting old permissions when the dialog came up. So to fix this I had to delete the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be because you have not granted the `user_birthday` permission while testing. 
You check the list of permissions you've granted to your app [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications).

If you have not. just delete the app from [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) **or** logout of the app; and then login again and give the permissions.